# Pandas SQL equivalent of update where group by

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

Despite looking for this, I cannot find the correct way to get an equivalent of this query working in pandas.

```
update product
  set maxrating = (select max(rating)
                   from rating
                   where source = 'customer'
                     and product.sku = rating.sku
                   group by sku)
  where maxrating is null;
```

Pandas

```
product = pd.DataFrame({'sku':[1,2,3],'maxrating':[0,0,1]})
rating = pd.DataFrame({'sku':[1,1,2,3,3],'rating':[2,5,3,5,4],'source':['retailer','customer','customer','retailer','customer']})
expected_result = pd.DataFrame({'sku':[1,2,3],'maxrating':[5,3,1]})
```

SQL

```
drop table if exists product;
create table product(sku integer primary key, maxrating int);
insert into product(maxrating) values(null),(null),(1);
drop table if exists rating; create table rating(sku int, rating int, source text);
insert into rating values(1,2,'retailer'),(1,5,'customer'),(2,3,'customer'),(2,5,'retailer'),(3,3,'retailer'),(3,4,'customer');
update product
  set maxrating = (select max(rating)
                   from rating
                   where source = 'customer'
                     and product.sku = rating.sku
                   group by sku)
  where maxrating is null;
select *
from product;
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
In [220]: product.ix[product.maxrating == 0, 'maxrating'] = product.sku.map(rating.groupby('sku')['rating'].max())

In [221]: product
Out[221]:
   maxrating  sku
0          5    1
1          3    2
2          1    3
```

or using common mask:

```
In [222]: mask = (product.maxrating == 0)

In [223]: product.ix[mask, 'maxrating'] = product.ix[mask, 'maxrating'].map(rating.groupby('sku')['rating'].max())

In [224]: product
Out[224]:
   maxrating  sku
0          5    1
1          3    2
2          1    3
```

Comment: Wow!!!! That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! Now, I just have to find if that's possible to use multiple columns for instead of just a series for the map method, otherwise I'll just use a calculated column.

Comment: @ArthurBurkhardt, you are welcome! I would suggest you to open a new question with a sample and desired data sets. You did it really great when you asked this question - it's much easier for SO community to work on an answer if we have a code for generating input and desired data sets

Answer (score 2):

#### All together

```
product.maxrating = product.maxrating.replace(0, np.nan)
missing = product.loc[product.maxrating.isnull(), 'sku']
missingmax = rating.groupby(missing, as_index=False).rating.agg({'maxrating': 'max'})
product.update(missingmax)
```

First, let's start with nulls instead of zeros

```
product.maxrating = product.maxrating.replace(0, np.nan)
product
```

[image]

Then identify the missing `'sku'`'s and use them in the `groupby` to calculate `missingmax`

```
missing = product.loc[product.maxrating.isnull(), 'sku']
missingmax = rating.groupby(missing, as_index=False).rating.agg({'maxrating': 'max'})

missingmax
```

[image]

Use `update`

```
product.update(missingmax)
product
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

```
In [127]: df = pd.merge(rating, product, on='sku')

In [128]: df1 = df[df['maxrating'] == 0].groupby('sku').agg({'rating': np.max}).reset_index().rename(columns={'rating': 'maxrating'})

In [129]: df2 = df[df['maxrating'] != 0][['sku', 'maxrating']].drop_duplicates(keep='first')

In [131]: pd.concat([df1, df2])
Out[131]: 
   sku  maxrating
0    1          5
1    2          3
3    3          1

In [132]: expected_result
Out[132]: 
   sku  maxrating
0    1          5
1    2          3
2    3          1
```

Basically, I merge both dataframes, then extract the rows that I need to process (those without maxrating), and find the actual maximum rating for them.

Once it's done, I concatenate the result with the rows I excluded (those with maxrating), and end up with the expected result.